# How to get attribute value of XML nodes using php?

Tags: php

I have a XML data stored in `$string` variable in php like this

```
<DATA>
<STOREITEMS>
  <CREATED date="Tue Oct 9 5:30:01 BST 2012">
    <CATEGORY id="442" name="Hen And Stag Nights"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="69" name="Games"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="252" name="Love Zone"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="202" name="Spotlight  Items"></CATEGORY>
  </CREATED>
  <CREATED date="Wed Oct 10 5:30:01 BST 2012">
    <CATEGORY id="442" name="Hen And Stag Nights"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="69" name="Games"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="252" name="Love Zone"></CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY id="202" name="Spotlight  Items"></CATEGORY>
  </CREATED>
</STOREITEMS>
<DATA>
```

I need to print date of  nodes using php

I have tried the following code

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$result = $xml->xpath("//DATA/STOREITEMS");

foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo $node->CREATED["date"];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

but it always return only

```
 Tue Oct 9 5:30:01 BST 2012
```

why its not returning like

```
Tue Oct 9 5:30:01 BST 2012 
Wed Oct 10 5:30:01 BST 2012
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$result` is a list of one (there is only one store item), so your `foreach` loops only once, and the CREATED it refers to is the first child.

Try this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$result = $xml->xpath("//DATA/STOREITEMS/CREATED"); // note the change

foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo $node["date"]; // note the change
    echo "<br />";
}
```